# Compare 2 different string columns in an SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select

I have two different columns of strings and I want to check if one is contained in the other and create a third column which has values of either 1 or 0( 1 if column2 contains column 1 and 0 if otherwise)
For example:

```
Column1          Column2          Column3
Spar             I am Sparta      1
How are you      Sparta           0
```

How do you do this string comparison in SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function. Assuming you just want to check if `colum1` is contained in `column2`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS column3
FROM   mytable
```

If you need to check both ways, just add another call:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0 OR
                 CHARINDEX(column2, column1) > 0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS column3
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH temp(col1, col2) AS(
    SELECT 'Spar', 'I am Sparta' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'How are you', 'Sparta'
)
SELECT
    *,
    col3 = 
        CASE
            WHEN col1 like '%' + col2 + '%' or col2 like '%' + col1 + '%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
FROM temp
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work

`select column1,column2, (case when column2 like '%' + column1 + '%' then 1 else 0 end) as column3 FROM yourtable`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
  (
     Column1 VARCHAR(20),
     Column2 VARCHAR(20)
  )

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES      ('Spar',
             'I am Sparta'),
            ('How are you',
             'Sparta')

SELECT column1,
       column2,
       CASE
         WHEN CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0
               OR CHARINDEX(column1, column2) > 0 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS column3
FROM   @table1
```